# Why can't I use a for...in loop in Set.prototype?

Tags: javascript

I want to go through all the functions in the `Set.prototype`.

`For...in` doesn't do it.

```js
var proto = Set.prototype;
for (var p in proto) {
  console.log(p);
}
// does ABSOLUTELY NOTHING
```

So my question has two parts:

> 1: Why does it not work?
>
> 2: How can I go through all the `Set.prototype` functions?

Comment: The properties are not enumerable.

Comment: Iterate over `Reflect.ownKeys(Set.prototype)` instead